# PDO insert not working bindParam bindValue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Even after having read all the 'PDO Insert not working' questions on S.O, I still can't figure out what's not working in the PDO SQL Query. Would love to have some help on that.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order_item` (`fk_order`,`fk_product`,`product_excl_tax`,`tax_product`,`shipping_excl_tax`,`tax_shipping`,`order_item_status`,`updated_at`)
VALUES (:theorderid, :product_id, :product_price, :price_incl_tax, :product_shipping, :product_shippingttc, :order_item_status, :dater)  "   ;

$req = $co_db->prepare($sql);
$req -> bindParam(':theorderid', $theorderid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req -> bindParam(':product_id', $product_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req -> bindParam(':product_price', $product_price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req -> bindParam(':price_incl_tax', $price_incl_tax, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req -> bindParam(':product_shipping', $product_shipping, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req -> bindParam(':product_shippingttc', $product_shippingttc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req -> bindParam(':order_item_status', $thestatus , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req -> bindParam(':dater', $thedate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: none... I tried everything but couldn't find

Comment: looking at your other questions; doesn't seem like there's anything related to databases and you may be new to this. One mistake that newbies do often, is to mix MySQL APIs when connecting/querying. When you say you've tried everything, that's rather broad. Everything that you know, sure... but really not "everything". Start by showing us your connection method, then the variables used for these. Sometimes it's a column's type, length that could be at fault and may fail silently. There isn't much else we can do here, sorry. Not till we know exactly which animal(s) we're dealing with.

Comment: What is result of `$req->errorInfo();`. Write that after `execute()` method

Comment: Your PDO connection settings should look like the setting in this [pastebin - questions/32690361 - interesting error handling - PDO Connection setup](http://pastebin.com/fcBQAtxA). And don't catch any exceptions.

Comment: Put the execute in try{}catch(Exceptions $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); echo $req->errorInfo();}

Comment: thanks @RyanVincent . I changed the configuration of my $co_db (the PDO object) and an error was reported on a field that couldn't be null.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RyanVincent I added the following lines to my PDO connect object declaration:

$co_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$co_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

It allowed me to see an error between the data I wanted to input and the restrictions set in MYSQL.